# Yii2 Model initialization AND session handeling

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Here's a pickle :) 
In the old Yii you could instantiate models anywhere in protected. Regardless of the module you were in. Then the Yii team decided to go and mess everything up :) and decided to change the structure and code and now, I'm a bit lost...

**1. HOW DO YOU INSTANTIATE MODELS?** (anywhere in the project)

Old fashion way was `$model = new Model();` where model could be in a totally different module and it would still work. How do we do this now? when I try to do it, it says: `Class 'app\modules\somemodule\controllers\Model' not found` which is funny because I want a model and it searches in controllers...

**2. SESSIONS IN YII**

Old fashion way was

```
Yii::app()->session['var'] = 'value';
echo Yii::app()->session['var']; // Prints "value"
```

How are they done now?

**L.E:** Found my answer to the second question :D and sessions are handled about the same: `Yii::$app->session['var'] = 'value';` the difference being the $... It's all about the $ :)

Thank you!
Ares.

Comment: Someone... ? no one... ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Funny how no one showed interest in my question...

Anyways, nothing changed about it. If you need new fresh instance it's just "new Post()". If you need to get AR model with data it's "Post::find->where(...)->one()"

**BUT** you have to:
Either import class from another namespace with use:

```
use app\modules\someModule\models\Post;

// ...

$post = new Post();
```

or use fully qualified class name:

```
$post = new \app\modules\someModule\models\Post();
```

Hope this helps others as well as it did me :D